# how to use SheetJS (js-xlsx) in angular 2

Tags: angular, xlsx

I'm learning angular2 and i wanted to use [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library in my project.

I installed xlsx `npm install xlsx`  and jszip `npm install jszip` and added them in my index.html

`<script src="node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>`

and added the typescript defitions `tsd install xlsx`

and I'm using webpack

but when I used it in

```
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx';
```

but i get error
`module build failed: error: cannot resolve module 'xlsx'`

Comment: can you update your answer with full working code so that it can help others like me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier method would be not using typings at all:

1. Add xlsx.core.min.js to your index.html file as you did.
   (I'm using angular-cli so my js files get copied to the dist/vendor directory)

   `<script src="vendor/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>`
2. In your module, do not use import but declare XLSX under your imports block.

   `declare var XLSX: any;`

If you're using angular-cli, you will need to add xlsx to your angular-cli-build.js file.

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'moment/moment.js',
       ....
      'xlsx/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]})
};
```

Comment: first thanks for help, but I want to use it with webpack do you know how ?

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 should work for you. Just make sure you set the correct location path for the .js file.

Comment: i already did step 1 and 2, but when i use XLSX object i get `ReferenceError: XLSX is not defined` in `XLSX.read`

Comment: do you know how to use this object or to initialize it ?

Comment: XLSX is initialized in the script xlsx.core.min.js when it is added in the head section of index.html. Are you making sure it is properly loaded and there are no 404 errors ?

Comment: i get 404 error, my include is  `<script src="./../node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>` and i'm sure this is the correct relative path

Comment: @RoyS. using `declare var XLSX: any;` gives me an error `Cannot find namespace 'XLSX'.`. Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 8):

The following is a working component who exports an xlsx file from an array of objects using js-xlsx lib on Angular 2/4:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { utils, write, WorkBook } from 'xlsx';

import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  table = [
    {
      First: 'one',
      Second: 'two',
      Third: 'three',
      Forth: 'four',
      Fifth: 'five'
    },
    {
      First: 'un',
      Second: 'deux',
      Third: 'trois',
      Forth: 'quatre',
      Fifth: 'cinq'
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    const ws_name = 'SomeSheet';
    const wb: WorkBook = { SheetNames: [], Sheets: {} };
    const ws: any = utils.json_to_sheet(this.table);
    wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
    wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
    const wbout = write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 
'binary' });

function s2ab(s) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0; i !== s.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  };
  return buf;
}

saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'exported.xlsx');
  }
}
```

You have to install xlsx and file-saver for this to work.

For the working example on exporting a xlsx file from an array of jsons on Angular2/4:

https://github.com/bogdancar/xlsx-json-to-xlsx-demo-Angular2

Answer (score 4):

tryout [ts-xlsx](https://github.com/DxCx/ts-xlsx), it's simple to use 
`npm install --save ts-xlsx` 
 then install the typings 
 `npm install --save @types/xlsx`

```js
/* You can use as namespace: */
import * as XLSX from 'ts-xlsx';
let wb: XLSX.IWorkBook = XLSX.read(...)

/* Or straight forward import */
import { read, IWorkBook } from 'ts-xlsx';
let wb: IWorkBook = read(...)
```

Comment: It does not write excel files

Comment: that wasn't mentioned in the question, I guess it's not fair to down vote my answer based on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Something else you might try is changing the link to use the full version, instead of core.  The following worked for me:

```
<script lang="javascript" src="dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

This will change with your path.  Yours would be:

```
<script src="node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For making xlsx work for angular 2+, you don't need any typings to be installed. Because the xlsx library contains the required typings in the package itself.

Step 1: Install xlsx using npm

```
npm install xlsx
```

Step 2: Import xlsx in your service/component.

`const XLSX = require('xlsx');`

```
OR
```

`import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';` -- (This did not work for me)

Step 3: You can use the XLSX as below.

```
XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed the xlsx package, e.g. "npm install --save xlsx".
It updated the package.json file with xlsx as a dependency. And now in my component I can import it, e.g. "import * as XLSX from 'xlsx' ".
I'm using Angular 4. I guess, in Angular 2 it should work exactly the same way.
P.S. There is no need to include the javascript file in the index.html.