# Cannot Find namespace XLSX on using module xlsx-style

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, typescript, js-xlsx

I am using **xlsx-style** npm module in my angular2 application for creating excels dynamically.
Reason for using xlsx-style rather than xlsx module is because I need to style the cells which is not possible using xlsx.

I have copied the xlsx.full.min.js from dist folder(from node_modules/xlsx-style) to assets folder and attached as a scritp tag to html page.

Ref : [how to use SheetJS (js-xlsx) in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804454/how-to-use-sheetjs-js-xlsx-in-angular-2)

I have imported the module into my component for namespace based access into my code.

```
declare var XLSX : any;
```

While building the app using ng build, I get the following error : Cannot find namespace 'XLSX'

Using @angular/cli @latest (Webpack)

Comment: Why don't you use ts-xlsx , It's what you are looking for, here's the link:
https://github.com/DxCx/ts-xlsx you can install it also by npm like this: npm install --save ts-xlsx good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can easily declare the module in some file e.g. `globals.d.ts`:

```
declare module "XLSX";
```

## More

Covered in the migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: I tried but still, the error message is coming.
I am putting the GitHub link for my code. Maybe you can understand what exactly is the issue with the code.

[link](https://github.com/ashishsantikari/excel-export-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare:

```
import { XLSX } from 'xlsx-style';
```