# How to download Excel file in angular 2

Tags: excel, angular, download, response

I am learning Angular 2 and I am trying to Download the Excel file in angular 2 by fetching customer data from sql server tables using web api.

After searching in google i found some code but using that code i am able  to download  but it does not contain the proper data and file name is also having some guid format

Below is the code i have used:

**Component**

```
GetRemindersData()
{
    var Flag="ALL_SPOTCHECK_RECORDS";
    this.httpService.GetRemindersData(Flag).subscribe(
        data=>this.downloadFile(JSON.stringify(data[1])),
        error => console.log("Error downloading the file."),
        () => console.info("OK"));
}

downloadFile(data:any){
    console.log(data);
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
public GetRemindersData(Flag:string){
    var GetRemindersData_URL:string = 'http://localhost:5000/api/RemindersData/?Flag='+Flag;
    return this.http.get(`${GetRemindersData_URL}`)
                .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Comment: You can create the excel file file on the front from the data you display. Look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44766181) to see how it's done.

Comment: After following above reference i am having error like 'coudld not find a declaration file for module 'xlsx'. '/node_modules
/xlsx/xlsx.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.'

Comment: I have an Angular demo app implementing `xlsx` [here](https://github.com/bogdancar/xlsx-json-to-xlsx-demo-Angular2). Clone it and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Actually i am not using angualr cli project but even though i tried  based on your code and i encounter an error like 'Could not find  a declaration file for module xlsx'

Comment: Again thanks for sharing the link and in code works in angular cli project. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Service return json ,it must return blob type,you can do like that

```
return this.http.get(url,{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
    (res) => {
        return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' })
    })
```

Also look at this post [angular2 file downlaod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816414/7261317)

Comment: After using above code i just got an undefined string value excel file

Comment: can you the backend respone

Comment: backed response is array of json objects

Comment: you need to give file response ,so that only we will handle blob response